# Class/package for German documentation

Tags: package-writing, documentation, documentclass-writing

I’m writing the [`musuos` class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/musuos) and I’m writing the documentation with `ltxdoc.cls` and `doc.sty` which seems to work. But the documentation is in German so it’s not very nice to get `(environment)` in the index instead of `(Umgebung)`.

[image: index output]

Is there a package that allows to change such entries?

BTW: Is there a better class/package to write a manual, or even one whose output looks better (like the one of the `biblatex` documentation)?

Comment: Are you using a package such as `enumerate` or `enumitem`. If so, you may want to look in the definitions of those packages if there's an index entry named "environment" that you could change suitably.

Comment: @Mico: No, the entries are generated by `\DescribeEnv` from `doc.sty`. It is pure coincidence that the examples in the picture are list environments …

Comment: A most useful hint! See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out p. 32 of the file `doc.pdf` (which you can get by typing `texdoc doc` on the command line) and lines 429, 431, 439, and 440 in particular. Open the file `doc.sty` in your favorite text editor, change the two instances of the string `(environment)` to `(Umgebung)`, and change the strings `environments:` to `Umgebungen:`. Finally, to avoid having to redo this work if and when the `doc` package is updated, you may want to save the file `doc.sty` to something like `tobidoc.sty`, store that file in your personal TeX directory, and run `texhash` if you use TeXlive (or, say, run MikTeX's filename database update routines). Oh, and be sure to load `tobidoc` instead of `doc` from now on. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Yes thanks, I’m my wrap this in a new package which adds my own macros for documenting packages.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself :-).
I copied these lines to my preamble and changed the relevant words …

```
\def\SpecialMainEnvIndex#1{\@bsphack\special@index{%
                                      #1\actualchar
                                      {\string\ttfamily\space#1}
                                         (environment)% <---------------------------- HERE
                                      \encapchar main}%
    \special@index{environments:\levelchar#1\actualchar{% <-------------------------- HERE
                   \string\ttfamily\space#1}\encapchar
           main}\@esphack}
\def\SpecialUsageIndex#1{\@bsphack
   {\let\special@index\index\SpecialIndex@{#1}{\encapchar usage}}%
   \@esphack}
\def\SpecialEnvIndex#1{\@bsphack
    \index{#1\actualchar{\protect\ttfamily#1}
           (environment)\encapchar usage}% <----------------------------------------- HERE
    \index{environments:\levelchar#1\actualchar{\protect\ttfamily#1}\encapchar& <---- HERE
           usage}\@esphack}
```

But it’s still interessting if there are better ways to do this …

Comment: If you think you need to change the strings `(environment)` and `environments:` more or less permanently, you might just edit the file `doc.sty` accordingly and save that file under a new name. That way, you won't clutter up the preamble needlessly.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better class/package to write a manual, or even one whose
>   output looks better (like the one of the biblatex documentation)?

The manual of the biblatex documentation class is typeset, using the `ltxdockit` class and you are right it looks very nice.